# one argument default value depends on the len(otherArgument)

Tags: python

```
def find (myStr,end=len(mystr)):
          ....
```

The default value of end should be len(myStr),
but that doesn't work. The default values are evaluated when the function is  defined, not when it is called. When find is defined, myStr doesn't exist yet, so you can't find its length.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  What is your question?

Comment: Probably a quarter of the functions in the stdlib do something like this, and they all do it the same way. (Well, many of them do it in C rather than in Python, but not all…) Have you tried looking at any of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
def find(myStr, end=None):
    end = len(myStr) if end is None else end
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def find(myStr, end=None):
...     end = len(myStr) if end is None else end
...     print end
...
>>> # end is set to the supplied value
>>> find("abc", 10)
10
>>> # end is set to the length of myStr (its default value)
>>> find("abc")
3
>>>
```

Comment: @user2281189 - Happy to have been of help!  Please don't forget to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) though.